# Retrieving multiple values selected on a form from a database

Tags: php

I’m attempting to create a string I can use in select statement that contains 3 multiple values serialize from another page. For instance:

```
$FullName1 = implode("' OR FullName = '", $_POST['FullName']);
$FullName2 = "FullName = '" . $FullName1;
$FullName0 = $FullName2 . "' ";

echo $FullName0;
```

Gives me “FullName = 'Joe Dirt' OR FullName = 'John Doe'
,
    $ProjectType1 = implode("' OR ProjectType = '", $_POST['ProjectType']);
    $ProjectType2 = "ProjectType = '" . $ProjectType1;
    $ProjectType0 = $ProjectType2 . "' ";

```
echo $ProjectType0;
```

Gives me “ProjectType = 'Customer Meetings' OR ProjectType = 'ESN Change'”
, and

```
$Company1 = implode("' OR Company = '", $_POST['Company']);
$Company2 = "Company = '" . $Company1;
$Company0 = $Company2 . "' ";

echo $Company0;
```

Gives me “Company = ' Acme ' OR Company = 'Airgas'”

What I want to do is arrange those three into something like

```
“$string = 
Company = 'Acme' AND ProjectType = 'Customer Meetings' AND FullName = 'Joe Dirt' 
OR 
Company = 'Acme' AND ProjectType = 'Customer Meetings' AND FullName = 'John Doe' 
OR
Company = 'Acme' AND ProjectType = 'ESN Change' AND FullName = 'Joe Dirt'
OR
Company = 'Acme' AND ProjectType = 'ESN Change' AND FullName = 'John Doe'
OR
Company = 'Airgas' AND ProjectType = 'Customer Meetings' AND FullName = 'Joe Dirt' 
OR 
Company = 'Airgas' AND ProjectType = 'Customer Meetings' AND FullName = 'John Doe' 
OR
Company = 'Airgas' AND ProjectType = 'ESN Change' AND FullName = 'Joe Dirt'
OR
Company = 'Airgas' AND ProjectType = 'ESN Change' AND FullName = 'John Doe'
OR
"
```

so I can the run a statement like

```
"SELECT * FROM Tracker WHERE ID > 0 AND $string ORDER BY Created DESC"
```

Also, if there's an easier way to do this, I'm for it! Thanks.

Comment: First of all, never use POST data directly in your query. The user can  manipulate it and abuse your database. it is called [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: I tried this;
    $info3 = "SELECT * FROM Tracker WHERE ID > 0 AND Company IN ('Acme', 'Airgas') AND ProjectType IN ('Customer Meetings', 'ESA Change') AND FullName IN ('Joe Dirt', 'John Doe')";
    $rs3=odbc_exec($conn1,$info3);
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs3)) {…
It does not produce an error, but nothing is retrieved.  I’m using MS Access as a backend a javascript to send the data from the form page to the page that looks up the information and return it to the form page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, use the inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="s[]" value="s1" />
<input type="text" name="s[]" value="s2" />
<input type="text" name="s[]" value="" />
```

The data in the $_REQUEST/$_POST/$_GET will look like this:

```
$_REQUEST["s"] = array("s1","s2",""); // attention: order may vary
```

so what you want to do is: strip empty values and trim the results:

```
$trimmed = array_map("trim",$_REQUEST["s"]); // all values are trimmed
$cleaned = array_filter($trimmed); // all empty strings were left out
```

so now you have an array with only valid values.
So you write your filter-string like this: use the SQL "in" operator ([see docu](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp))

```
// I assume you have an array of filters called $filters
// I assume you have an SQL connection object called $db - @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php for details
// I assume you are familiar with protection methods against SQL injections like mysqli::real_escape_string
if ( count($cleaned) )
{
  $escaped = array_map(array($db, "real_escape_string"), $cleaned); 
  $filters[] = "FullName in ('". implode("','", $escaped) ."')";
}
```

And if you are done with all your filters, you write your query like this:

```
$qry = "select x from y". ( count($filters) ? " where ". implode(" and ", $filters) : "" ) ." order by z desc" ;
```

You could repeat the described technique to get a string like

```
select * from Tracker where Company in ('Acme','Airgas') and ProjectType in ('Customer Meetings','ESN Change') and FullName in ('John Doe','Joe Dirt') order by Created desc
```

Another hint: you could use the technique for names in  also with array keys and also in checkboxes or multiple-select-fields

```
<input type="checkbox" name="x[1]" value="a"/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="x[2]" value="b"/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="x[3]"  value="c"/> 

<select name="y[]" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

With this knowledge you should be able to adapt the code to your needs, write some pretty little functions to get your code tidy and always remember: beware of the SQL injection.

<sub>whole code comes untested. wrote it only to give you an idea what to do</sub>